# Constructor (java.awt.Polygon) is undefined

Tags: java

My code here is returning the error: The constructor VectorSprite(java.awt.Polygon) is undefined

```
import java.awt.Polygon;


public class Rock extends VectorSprite{
    int size;
    public Rock(){
      super(new Polygon(new int[] {20, 15, 30 ,50, 40, 35}, new int[]{5,  30,  45, 15, 10, 5},6)); //error here

        velocityx = (float)Math.random() * 6 - 3;
        velocityy = (float)Math.random() * 6 - 3;

    }

    public Rock (int size){
        this();
        this.size = size;
    }
    @Override
    public void updatePosition(){
        angle += Math.PI/180;
      super.updatePosition();
    }
    public void rockspawn(float x, float y){
       float randAng;
       randAng = (float)Math.random() * (float)Math.PI * 2;

       posx = x + ((float)Math.cos(randAng)*150);
       posy = y + ((float)Math.sin(randAng)*150);

    }
}
```

VectorSprite's constructor is giving the error. It looks like this:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Polygon;

public class VectorSprite {
    float posx;
    float posy;
    Color color;
    Polygon shape;
    float velocityx;
    float velocityy;
    double angle;

int[] xp = {20,50 ,30 };
int[] yp = {15,10 ,30 };

    public VectorSprite(){
    posx = 30;
    posy = 30;
    color = Color.GREEN;
    shape = new Polygon(xp,yp,3);
    velocityx = 0;
    velocityy = 0;
    }
   public void draw(Graphics g) {
       g.drawPolygon(shape);
   }
   public void updatePosition() {
      posx = posx + velocityx  ;  
      for (int i = 0; i < shape.npoints; i++){
        shape.xpoints[i] += velocityx;
        shape.ypoints[i] += velocityy;

      }         
}

}
```

What's the problem here? I'm sorry for being so vague, but this is really old code and I'm brand new to the scene. I'll try to answer any clarifying questions.

Comment: Look at the ***complete*** error message, post it here as well (you're currently not doing this) as it tells you *exactly* what is wrong. Then look at the Polygon API to see what constructors are in fact allowed.

Comment: That is the complete error message. It doesn't say anything else besides that.

Comment: Ah, my bad -- does VectorSprite have a constructor that accepts a Polygon? If so, please show it to us. Your code assumes that it does as you're calling `super(...)` passing in a Polygon. If it does not have this constructor, then you can't do this, pure and simple.

Comment: Perhaps you want to do just this -- give VectorSprite such a constructor, and use it to set the polygon field of the class.

Comment: Ok I'm an idiot. I just got rid of super() and it works now. You were right. Thanks!